# dse-agents leaking filedescriptors and memory

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Every time we backup our 3 nodes DSE cluster (5.1.2), Datastax agents (6.1.2) leak memory (~ 25MB) and filedescriptors (~ 1800).

Since we make quite frequent backups, this is rather annoying.

Is this a know issue or a normal behaviour (may be the FD & RAM usage settles after a while) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be OPSC-12900 'Backups leaking file handles', an issue seen with the datastax-agent.

If you review an `lsof -p <agent pid>` and find that the vast majority of handles/descriptors are referencing snapshot directories, this is a likely candidate.

I recommend raising a ticket with Datastax support to get the latest status on this.